# Find the interval on which the following function is increasing or decreasing; $f(x)=\ln(x-14)-2x$

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $f(n)=\ln(x-14)-2x$? If I knew that I might be able to finish it off thank you.

Comment: There wasn't an $x$ on the last term in the title.  I added it based on the body.  Did I do the right thing?

Comment: Oops sorry thank you can you help please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you have two pieces of your function.  Can you take the derivative of either?  Do you know the [chain rule?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)  It is useful for the first piece.

Comment: Yes I know the chain rule but unsure of it in relation to ln?

Comment: $\ln$ is a function.  So in the expression $f(g(x)), g(x)=x-14, f$ is $\ln$

Comment: But where would the -2x go into the chain rule? Or would I just leave it out? I thought I could only use the chain rule when a bracket is raised to a power.

Comment: The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives.  So you take the derivative of $-2x$ and add it to the derivative of $\ln(x-14)$.  It is only the latter that needs the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Given $f(x)=\ln(x-14)-2x$ we can take the derivative and obtain $f'(x)={1\over x-14}-2$. Are you comfortable with this?

Comment: Thank you Ross but how do I know where what x is where is algebra like that?

Comment: What does "where what x is where is algebra like that" mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Oh so sorry I mean because I have to find the increasing and decreasing values I have too find where the function crosses the x axis and find values for x. How do you find the values of x for your answer?

Comment: For what values of $x$ is $f'(x)=0$. This can help you figure out the increasing and decreasing values. Do you see why?