# Increasing and Decreasing Functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

f(x) = ln(x - 14) - 2x

Could someone please do this question and explain the different steps involved.

Comment: What are we supposed to "do"? And we don't "do" questions, we just help with them.

Comment: Stop changing your username every time you ask a new question. And please, before asking more questions about where a function is increasing and decreasing, READ your earlier answers to half a dozen similar posts yesterday, all asking where a function is increasing and decreasing. The steps have all been explained. I am going to flag the site moderators, because you are taking advantage of the site, and don't seem to be learning anything from the answers given nor from earlier comments addressing this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate [Find the interval on which ln(x - 12) - 2x is increasing or decreasing.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564556/find-the-interval-on-which-the-following-function-is-increasing-or-decreasing). Same question by user "Anne", yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

STEPS:

- Find the domain on which $f(x)$ is defined.
- Find $f'(x)$
- Solve for $f'(x) = 0$, to determine the endpoints of intervals (where $f(x)$ is neither increasing nor decreasing). There will be only one such point for this particular function.
- Then, the one interval on which $f(x)$ is increasing is where $f'(x) > 0$. And the one interval on which $f(x)$ is decreasing is where $f'(x) < 0$. (Keep in mind that the intervals here *cannot include* where $f(x)$ is undefined.)

Now you've got all you need to handle this problem and answer your question.

Comment: Welcome back Amy. :+)

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\text{for}\ x>14,\quad f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-14}-2\geq 0\iff x\le\frac{29}{2}=14.5$$
so $f$ is increasing on $]14,14.5]$ and decreasing on $[14.5,+\infty[$.

Comment: You can do it, but can you *explain it???*

Comment: The sign of  $f'$ determinates  the  monotony of the function $f$

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ ${}$